# How to get list of assets into js code (for cache.addAll(assets) for PWA)

Tags: vite

I'm building a PWA and part of the startup in the service worker is to cache all the assets. But since vite (by default) inserts the hash of the generated assets into their file names, the exact list of assets to cache varies from run to run, making it impossible to cache the assets.

So how can I access an array of built assets from inside a `*.js` file at run-time, so I can cache them with `cache.addAll(assets)`?

While that is what I'd really like, I do know there are (at least) two workarounds:

- Remove `-[hash]` from `build.rollupOptions.output.(asset|entry|chunk)Filenames`. That gives a predictable list of assets that can be hard-coded.
- Use [VitePWA](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/). It generates the list of assets "somehow" into the `sw.js` file. But my PWA is already working fine without vite or VitePWA, and I'd like to avoid including this huge dependency. I'd just like to build what I already have with vite (+add Vue3) and be done.

### How does [VitePWA](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/) do it?

The source code for the [VitePWA](https://github.com/vite-pwa/vite-plugin-pwa/blob/31ccaa89bb18b7d39f8d150435b26d33dfee04dd/src/index.ts#L10) plugin is really an array of 4 plugins that interact in a way I haven't been able to understand.

I'm guessing these are rollup plugins and the path forward is to create a rollup plugin that somehow investigates what assets got created by the other plugins and then in a post step creates a `assets.js` or something containing something like:

```js
export const assets = [
  "/assets/index-4f46e888.js",
  "/assets/index-ef4f98ff.css",
  "/assets/link-192-a96fcf4c.png",
  "/assets/logo-277e0e97.svg",
  "/assets/modulepreload-polyfill-3cfb730f.js",
  "/assets/otherPage-892792b9.js",
  "/favicon.ico",
  "/index.html",
  "/otherPage.html",
]
```

That leaves me with two questions about a "like-VitePWA" approach:

- How do I go about creating something like `assets.js` above?
- How would I be able to access `const assets` from the javascript in `index.html`? There seems to be a chicken-and-egg situation. Can I tell rollup that exactly `assets.js` needs to be loaded at *runtime* and not *compile time* somehow? Or how do I "stuff* `const assets` into the bundle in my post step?

### Remove `-[hash]` from `build.rollupOptions.output.(asset|entry|chunk)Filenames`

This was relatively easy. Put this under `build.rollupOptions` in `vite.config.js`:

```js
      output: {
        assetFileNames: "assets/[name][extname]",
        entryFileNames: "assets/[name].js",
        chunkFileNames: "assets/[name].js",
        sourcemap: true,
      }
```

And voila, the output from `npm build` in `dist/` becomes predictable.

But it is no longer cache-busting because the `-[hash]` has been removed. Which is why I'm looking for a way to keep the `-[hash]` so it remains cache-busting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plugin that prepends a global `window.assetList` to the code of the `index` chunk when used as:

```js
import assetListPlugin from './assetListPlugin.js'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    ...,
    assetListPlugin('assetList', 'index'),
    ...,
  ],
})
```

And here is ./assetListPlugin.js`:

```js
export default (global, chunkName) => ({
    name: 'assetList',

    generateBundle(outputOptions, bundle) {
        let chunkToModify
        const allAssetFileNames = []
        Object.values(bundle).forEach((asset) => {
            if (asset.name == chunkName && asset.type == 'chunk')
                chunkToModify = asset
            allAssetFileNames.push(asset.fileName)
        })
        if (! chunkToModify) {
            throw new Error(`No "${chunkName}" chunk found`)
        }
        chunkToModify.code = `window.${global} = ${JSON.stringify(allAssetFileNames)}; ${chunkToModify.code}`
    },
})
```

Use it in any code in the `index` chunk as:

```js
// assetList is now a global variable
console.log(assetList)
```

What suprised me a little was that it only works for `vite build`, not `vite` (dev server). But it makes sense. dev only knows about the modules it has served thus far, since it doesn't build everything up-front, so it can't populate the full asset array. This is also [documented](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#universal-hooks) as:

> Output Generation Hooks (except closeBundle) are not called during dev.

(So `generateBundle()` is never called during `vite` (dev server))

So if I want to do this, run `vite build -w` in one terminal and `vite preview` in another.